# Como mostrar notificación desde Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas de un pequeño programa de chat offline en linux. 
He creado (o mas bien simulado) un demonio que compruebe que cuando haya cambios en ciertos ficheros lo notifique usando el comando "`notify-send`".

Si lanzo el programa por la terminal, aparece el mensaje perfectamente, sin embargo, al ejecutarse el programa cargado como un demonio (he creado el correspondiente enlace en `/etc/rc5.d/S01xxxx` al ejecutable que esta en `/etc/init.d/xxxx`) no me muestra la notificación, aunque las comprobaciones si que las hace bien (lo se porque ademas guardo un log).

**¿como puedo hacer para que cuando haya una notificacion se muestre en el escritorio (o en la terminal)?**

He probado tambien con comandos como `wall, write` etc y ninguno da señales de vida.

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!